# How to auto-format cpplint?

Tags: c++, clion, cpplint

I'm using Clion to develop C++ programs. For unifying code style, our team introduced cpplint to our project. Since previous codes didn't follow cpplint's code style, a large number of errors need to be fixed.

I have tried to set Clion's *C/C++/code style* as *Google* and open *settings-code_style-enable_ClangFormat*, but the auto-format function doesn't cover most of cpplint's style.

How can I auto-format these codes?

Comment: Clang-Format provides a lot of options to configure how the code should be formatted: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html At first sight it may be a bit overwhelming, but it should be able to get your code formatted (almost) the way you need it with the proper options.

Comment: @user1810087 That's what I have tried, but it doesn't work when in the editor. The common mistakes(like `No copyright message found.`) aren't highlighted in the editor.

Comment: @Striezel I find that `Clang-format` has `Google` style, but it only autoformats some non-functional areas like index space or redundant line.

Comment: If the target doesn't address your issue, please [edit] the question to state precisely why that solution fails for you.

Comment: @syheliel: The styles like `Google`, `LLVM`, etc. that can be set via `BasedOnStyle` are just a starting point for individual configurations. There are so much more options to customize the way the code is formatted. Try experimenting with other settings, it may get you closer to the desired formatting.